# Applying SUPEE-6788, it removes static block on home page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

Today I applied patch SUPEE-6788 and I noticed that the static block on my home page disappeared.

I have checked in admin side, i have used `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="10"`  and `{{block type="responsivebannerslider/index" name="responsivebannerslider_index"`

Similarly I have used many other blocks in my Magento sites.

I have read on google and found the solution to manually add these blocks in System -> Permissions -> Blocks.

Ok, I have manually added two `catalog/product_list` and `responsivebannerslider/index`, and they're working fine.

But my problem is, I don't know how many block I have added in my magento sites. It is not possible for me to manually add these block in System -> Permissions -> Blocks.

Please help. How to solve this issue?

Comment: This script will find all the block you need to white-list https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox

Answer (score 2):

You will need to whitelist your blocks if they are not already whitelisted. Navigate to `System > Permissions > Blocks`. You can read more on this here: http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

You can also install this toolbox script on your site to find issues with modules related to the patch update. https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox

I strongly suggest not letting the script fix any problems for you, especially on a production site. I would recommend running the analyze code instead.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is adding cms/block to Magento white list. 
Go to System -> Configuration -> Permissions ->Blocks and add row named "cms/block" with status Allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this addon for Magerun: https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons#find-non-whitelisted-varsblocks-to-be-compatible-with-supee-6788-and-magento-1922 to find all used custom blocks and variables.