# emails in spam after security patch 6788 installation in magento

Tags: php, security, magento

Recently I applied security patch 6788 on magento store, but there are some issues after installation like some blockes disappeared from home page and sales emails are in spam/junk folder.

I was able to fix blocks issue but could not solve spam emails.

I have tried different threads on internet, but it did not help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Emails ending up in the spam box are due to template created email content (rework it to sound less spammy), failure to provide a proper email source with SPF records, failure to use an SMTP service that uses TLS security to transfer email and authentication to restrict access. None of the above are in the venue of this section.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks disappearing are due to the need now to register variables and CMS blocks in a whitelist for inclusion in templates. You will need to read through your home page content for entries similar to `{{block type="cms/block"}}` and add the type (in this case `cms/block`) to the whitelist in `System =>Permissions =>Blocks`

[Applying SUPEE-6788, it removes static block on home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433109/applying-supee-6788-it-removes-static-block-on-home-page)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87897/553

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88111/added-block-to-whitelist-but-blocks-still-not-showing-6788